# QML TreeView: Show tool tip

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to display a `QFileSystemModel` with a QML `TreeView`. I would like to show the filename as a tool tip (as the space is limited, long filenames cannot be displayed and thus I want to display them as tool tip). I override the data function of the model (in my class derived from `QFileSystemModel`) like this

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
{
    if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::ToolTipRole) {
        return QVariant(fileInfo(index).fileName());
    }
```

What do I need to do in my `TreeView` in order to show the tool tip?

```
  TreeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        sortIndicatorVisible: true
        model: fileSystemModel
        rootIndex: rootPathIndex
        selection: sel
        selectionMode: 2


        TableViewColumn {
            id: namecolumn
            title: "Name"
            role: "fileName"

            resizable: true
            width: parent.width-sizeWidth-dateWidth-scrollBarWidth
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            id: sizecolumn
            title: "Size"
            role: "size"
            resizable: false
            width: sizeWidth

        }
  }
```

Comment: Create a custom item delegate and use the ToolTip QML type in that one. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#itemDelegate-prop

Comment: Yes, that might work. So TableView does not support tool tips out of the box? I ask because the Widget version does, right?

Comment: Thats right. The standard delegate used in qml does not support tooltips. It's simply less capable then the widgets version

Comment: Maybe you should post your question as an answer, as it works for me.